# Is there any way to setOnItemclickListener for a Linear Layout with more than one child item

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have a Linear Layout with more than 1 child item is there any way to set onItemClickListener for my Linear layout?

Here is xml file

```
  <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:layout_height="80dp"
               android:padding="1dp"
               android:src="@drawable/fish"
               android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
               />
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:layout_height="80dp"
               android:padding="1dp"
               android:src="@drawable/fruits"
               android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:layout_height="80dp"
               android:padding="1dp"
               android:src="@drawable/vegetables"
               android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:layout_height="80dp"
               android:padding="1dp"
               android:src="@drawable/oils"
               android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What did you just say? You should definitely refer `findViewById()` again.

Comment: why  ............? this is like right question for the wrong requirement !

Comment: @Wizard  bro I dont want set onClickListener for my Linear Layout, you didn't get my question..

Comment: If you want to do it in this way there is no point of the concept of list views , you are just not doing the right thing

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is

```
for(int i= 0 ; i < linearLayout.getChildCount() ; i++){
   View view  = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
   view.setTag(i);
   view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           int position = (int) v.getTag();
        }
   });
}
```

other way is to extends LinearLayout and create one with this functionality

Comment: Thanks, but how to get item at position?? I like a gridView gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cilicked "+categoriesImageAdapter.getItem(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHOR‌​T).show(); } });

Comment: i update my code.. this way you can get the position of the view

Answer (score 0):

Just set

```
android:clickable="true"
```

to the LinearLayout. Also, don't forget to provide onClickListener to the view when you inflate it.

Comment: post an answer when you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your LinearLayout, inside activity get a reference to that linear layout and set onClickListener to that object

Comment: I want to set onClickListener for child of Linear Layout like a gridView gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cilicked "+categoriesImageAdapter.getItem(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHOR‌​T).show(); } });

Comment: Sorry, I did not see onItemClickListener. You should use recyclerView or something similar for this case. Don't start reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

first set id of LinearLayout in your XML.
and then set OnClickeListener on this LinearLayout from your code.

**Try This.**

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

       ...

   </LinearLayout>

 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

 linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do what you want.
                }
            });
```

Comment: I want to set onClickListener for child of Linear Layout like a gridView            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Cilicked "+categoriesImageAdapter.getItem(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not understand the difference between an `AdapterView` widgets and basic `ViewGroups` .. There is no way to set one listener with a position argument out-of-the-box on `LinearLayout`..

You can however subclass it, expose an interface and iterate over child elements. On each one of them set an `OnClickListener` which just calls the implementation of your exposed interface along with index of this element in the iteration.

```
public class MyLinearLayout {

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onClick(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```